# Standalone connections in TypeORM versions greater than 0.3.0

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

In the TypeORM versions smaller than 0.3.0 you could create normal connections:

```ts
const createdConnection: Connection = await createConnection(options);
```

And then, this connection was usable like this:

```ts
MyModel.useConnection(connection);
```

And the connection could be closed without any problems after the database tasks were complete:

```ts
connection.close();
```

I´ve never had any issues regarding connection pooling in previous versions of typeorm.
But since the 0.3.0 update (now i´m on 0.3.7) i´m constantly getting the error

```
Pool is closed
```

It seems to me, that the datasource type does not act independently anymore, like the connection type did in the previous versions.

Is there a way to get this behaviour back?